# How to pass a mock into a spy constructor?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Test {

    @Mock private A a;
    @Spy private B b = new B(a);
```

When 'b' is constructed 'a' is still null. Once the unit test hits some methods 'a' will be not null.

Is there a way to construct a spy 'b' with a non null mock 'a'?

Comment: You can always do it programmatically instead of annotations.

Comment: Doing it programmatically did work. I am curious if there is a way of doing it with annotations.

Comment: As far as I can tell, no. `b` is populated when the `Test` instance is constructed, and `a` is populated later by Mockito. That is unless Mockito changes the bytecode of `Test` to intercept instance construction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to move it into an `@Before` annotated method.